# Having difficulty getting transmission to work on headless pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I get the following when I try, and to be honest, I don't know what the error message means:

---

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service transmission-daemon start
Job for transmission-daemon.service failed. See 'systemctl status transmission-daemon.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

---

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Sun 2016-04-24 09:01:19 UTC, end at Sun 2016-04-24 16:47:40 UTC. --
Apr 24 16:47:36 raspberrypi sudo[1054]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
Apr 24 16:47:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Transmission BitTorrent Daemon...
-- Subject: Unit transmission-daemon.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit transmission-daemon.service has begun starting up.
Apr 24 16:47:36 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1078]: [2016-04-24 16:47:36.856 UTC] Couldn't read "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json": Permission denied
Apr 24 16:47:36 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1078]: [2016-04-24 16:47:36.856 UTC] transmission-daemon Error loading config file -- exiting. (daemon.c:519)
Apr 24 16:47:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Apr 24 16:47:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Transmission BitTorrent Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit transmission-daemon.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit transmission-daemon.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Apr 24 16:47:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit transmission-daemon.service entered failed state.
Apr 24 16:47:36 raspberrypi sudo[1054]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 24 16:47:40 raspberrypi sudo[1086]: pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xn
Apr 24 16:47:40 raspberrypi sudo[1086]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
```

---

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status transmission-daemon.service
● transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-04-24 16:47:36 UTC; 32s ago
  Process: 1078 ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 1078 (code=exited, status=255)

Apr 24 16:47:36 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1078]: [2016-04-24 16:47:36.856 UTC] Couldn't read "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json": Permission denied
Apr 24 16:47:36 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[1078]: [2016-04-24 16:47:36.856 UTC] transmission-daemon Error loading config file -- exiting. (daemon.c:519)
Apr 24 16:47:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Apr 24 16:47:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Transmission BitTorrent Daemon.
Apr 24 16:47:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit transmission-daemon.service entered failed state.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Output of: `namei -lx namei -lx /var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json`

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ namei -lx /var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
f: /var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
Drwxr-xr-x root root                /
drwxr-xr-x root root                var
drwxr-xr-x root root                lib
drwxr-xr-x pi   pi                  transmission-daemon
drwxr-xr-x pi   pi                  .config
drwsr-x--- pi   pi                  transmission-daemon
lrwxrwxrwx pi   pi                  settings.json -> /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
Drwxr-xr-x root root                  /
drwxr-xr-x root root                  etc
drwxrwsr-x root debian-transmission   transmission-daemon
-rw------- pi   pi                    settings.json
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the looks of it, `transmission-daemon` either starts running as some non-root user other that `pi`, or drops privileges to some non-root user. Try:

```
sudo chmod 644 /var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

and restart.